# overflow-y hide submenu

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've got a list with certain height, and need to make it scroll to show the rest vertically.
So I added `overflow-y: hidden;` to the list.
But the submenu can't be visible, and a horizontal scrollbar showed.

Is there any solution? 
[code here](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/tGdFJ)

Comment: Your UL has a width set. as soon as you remove it then you can access the submenu. Else it must be done in Javascript to make a seperate menu for sub

Comment: I need width, this ul itself is a long dropdown, and the ul inside is it's submenu

Answer (score 0):

Simply increase the width of the .wrapper

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  /* I need overflow-y auto,but I also need to display the submenu*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```